# Trying to find all the arguments relating to gods

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

I'm trying to build a list of every argument relating to the existence, likelihood, evidence etc... of God in the Abrahamic tradition, or gods and the supernatural in general. I specifically want to build the list of arguments and not the responses and counter-responses since I hope I'm right in saying that the general argument themes are finite while the variety of responses (good or not) will be too many to pragmatically list. I do hope to start studying each argument and their responses but have no goal of making an exhaustive list of responses.

From a survey I found online I have these arguments accounted for:

- Argument from incoherence
- pragmatic argument for atheism
- Argument from parsimony
- Argument from poor design
- Argument from lack of evidence
- Argument from inconsistent revelations
- Argument from divine hiddenness
- Argument from evil
- Ontological argument
- Moral argument
- Pragmatic argument (pascals wager)
- Argument from miracles
- Argument from beauty
- Argument from religious experience
- Cosmological argument
- Argument from design

So if you know a major philosophical argument on this topic that I don't have yet please let me know, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you add a sentence that describes each point? As one example, state what you mean by "Moral argument". This brief description leaves open a very wide range of ideas.

Comment: This is a list question and is entirely too broad for the Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to look at Rebecca Newberger Goldstein's book [36 Arguments for the Existence of God: A Work of Fiction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AK2NNYI); she is the wife of Steven Pinker.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I had heard about her book before but didn't look into it because I didn't think she was a philosopher. I'm seeing now that she is though so I'll definitely be checking it out.

I wanted to avoid books by non-philosophers since there are a number out there that I've heard present arguments with a lot of holes in them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a famous, humorous resource for that, called [Hundreds of Proofs of God’s Existence](http://www.godlessgeeks.com/LINKS/GodProof.htm). Since you listed a few bulleted items, this page fits the bill quite nicely.

Comment: (1) God exists.
(2) Therefore, God exists.
lol solid logic.

Comment: @Epistechne: There are #136 and #162 also.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also think more about the arguments of beauty and miracle, that’s of course my own idea. We all have the capacity to think in a scientific way about our universe, about our existence etc and how all this changes with respect to time. One will study biology to investigate the origin of species, one will study physics/mathematics to describe all in a rational way... We can  bring together all these disciplines and see how they describe one big system in DIFFERENT languages. The key word here is *difference*: all different scientific disciplines confirm each other in studying a really big universe, which is (according to me) not due to coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few:

Argument from dirty jokes / scary stories ( https://stjohnoneone.com/2014/11/12/a-simple-argument-for-christian-theology-c-s-lewis/ )

Argument from injustice ( https://www.dacc.edu/assets/pdfs/PCM/merechristianitylewis.pdf#page=25 )

Argument from meaning ( https://www.dacc.edu/assets/pdfs/PCM/merechristianitylewis.pdf#page=26 )

Argument from history ( https://www.reasonablefaith.org/writings/popular-writings/jesus-of-nazareth/the-challenge-of-history-an-interview-with-william-lane-craig/ )

Incorrect straw man sort-of-resembling the Kalam Cosmological Argument ( https://www.reasonablefaith.org/writings/popular-writings/existence-nature-of-god/36-arguments-for-the-existence-of-god-goldstein-on-the-cosmological-argumen/ )

The Cosmological Argument from Contingency ( https://www.reasonablefaith.org/writings/popular-writings/existence-nature-of-god/the-new-atheism-and-five-arguments-for-god/ )

The Euthyphro Dilemma ( https://www.reasonablefaith.org/writings/popular-writings/existence-nature-of-god/the-new-atheism-and-five-arguments-for-god/ )

The Teleological Argument / Argument from Design from Fine-Tuning ( https://www.reasonablefaith.org/writings/popular-writings/existence-nature-of-god/the-new-atheism-and-five-arguments-for-god/ )

Warranted Christian Belief ( http://home.sogang.ac.kr/sites/sgphilobk21/%EC%9E%90%EB%A3%8C%EC%8B%A4/Lists/b8/Attachments/3/warranted_christian_belief_alvin_plantinga.pdf )

> This book is about the intellectual or rational acceptability of Christian belief. When I speak here of Christian belief, I mean what is common to the great creeds of the main branches of the Christian church, what unites Calvin and Aquinas, Luther and Augustine, Menno Simons and Karl Barth, Mother Teresa and St. Maximus the Confessor, Billy Graham and St. Gregory Palamas—classical Christian belief, as we might call it.  [*Warranted Christian Belief by Alvin Plantinga, Ph.D*](http://home.sogang.ac.kr/sites/sgphilobk21/%EC%9E%90%EB%A3%8C%EC%8B%A4/Lists/b8/Attachments/3/warranted_christian_belief_alvin_plantinga.pdf#page=9)